# Cordova 9.1 Android Application white screen for Android 10- (works for Android 10 +)

Tags: angular, cordova-android

I created a small angular application where I added Cordova to generate a web and android application.

Everything was ok when I used angular version 6 and Cordova-android version 8.

Some weeks ago, I updated the versions of my application to use Angular 13 and Cordova-android 9.1.

The problem in production is that the application only works for sdkversion 29+.

I don't have any error when I debug the application.

Can someone help me?

More information:

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "myApp",
  "displayName": "myApp",
  "version": "1.5.5",
  "description": "myApp description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<widget id="io.cordova.myApp" version="1.5.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
        MyApp description
    </description>
    <author email="myApp@gmail.com" href="http://cordova.io">
        MyApp Owner
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="145000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
        <icon src="/src/assets/icon_36.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="/src/assets/icon_48.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="/src/assets/icon_72.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="/src/assets/icon_96.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="/src/assets/icon_144.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="/src/assets/icon_192.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="100000" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: not sure but it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73957203/bug-android-10-api-29-app-launches-with-white-screen

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your target is set to 'es5' in the 'tsconfig.json' file. Here's the our 'tsconfig.json' configuration:

{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
"node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
"es2018",
"dom"
]
}
}