# Bug: Android 10 API 29 App launches with white screen

Tags: android, capacitor, angular14, ionic6

### **Bug Report**

E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/ - Line 286 - Msg: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
E/Capacitor: JavaScript Error: {"type":"js.error","error":{"message":"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?","url":"http://localhost/vendor.js","line":48478,"col":28,"errorObject":"{}"}}
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 48478 - Msg: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/ - Line 286 - Msg: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
E/Capacitor: JavaScript Error: {"type":"js.error","error":{"message":"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .","url":"http://localhost/main.js","line":1798,"col":26,"errorObject":"{}"}}
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main.js - Line 1798 - Msg: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

> App works fine on android 12 but not with android 10 (API 29) and below

**Capacitor Version**

```
Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/core: 4.2.0
  @capacitor/cli: 4.2.0
  @capacitor/android: 4.2.0
  @capacitor/ios: Not installed
```

**Platform(s)**

Android

**Current Behavior**

App launches with white screen

**Code Reproduction**

```
ionic start
Angular
Tabs
```

**Other Technical Details**

```
npm --version output: 7.24.0

node --version output: v16.10.0

pod --version output : 1.11.3
```

**Additional Context**

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5972

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Despite the unclear description, this post solved my issue, thanks to Q&A authors.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed, angular, by default, only supports latest 2 android versions, if you want to support older versions you have to configure your app to compile to es2015.

Change your "target": "es2020" to "target": "es2015", inside tsconfig.json file under compilerOptions.

Please refer https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5972